# nodejs POST request.post not working

Tags: node.js

I need to use request.post for sending a value to a server.

The url is: http://192.168.0.100/control/thermostat.cgi?param=thermostat_manualsetpoint

Value to send as plain text: 2000

Until now I've tried something like this, but it's not working:
a button in the app that should POST the temperature value:

```
HEAT17 : { states: [{ label:'Heat:17°', action:'', icon:'fa-fire',
          serverExecute:function(node){
          var targetNow=0, modeNow='';
                  var thejson = '2000';
                  var param = 'thermostat_manualsetpoint';
                  exports.tstatRequest(param, thejson, node._id);
                            },
                         }],
                  breakAfter:true,
               },
```

The function exports.tstatRequest is:

```
    exports.tstatRequest = function(param, thejson, nodeId) {
  //console.log('tstatRequest:' + JSON.stringify(thejson));
  db.findOne({ _id : nodeId }, function (err, dbNode) {
    var thermostatIP = dbNode.settings && dbNode.settings.ip ? dbNode.settings.ip : (exports.motes[dbNode.type].settings.ip || settings.radiothermostat.ip.value);
    //console.log('URL: ' + 'http://'+thermostatIP+'/control/thermostat.cgi?param=' + param);
    request.post({ url: 'http://'+thermostatIP+'/control/thermostat.cgi?param=thermostat_manualsetpoint', body:'2000'},

              function(error,response,body){
                console.log('BODY: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
                if (error) console.log('ERROR in tstatRequest(): ' + JSON.stringify(thejson) + ' nodeId:' + nodeId + ' - ' + error);
                else exports.tstatPoll(nodeId); //now ask for a refresh of status from thermostat (HTTP GET)
              }
    );
  });
}
```

I've tried in Advanced REST Client and the post query works like this:
[Test query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdIdK.jpg)

Comment: "It's not working" - Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have the request inserted in a nodejs app and it should change the thermostat_manualsetpoint value (I see that value in a webpage). That value doesn't get changed but I also don't see any error in the shell.

Comment: @Kylix do you see an error in the `body` argument in your callback? Have you looked at the `response.statusCode` you are getting back? `error` is usually reserved for an error in the application, not a 400/500 error response.

Comment: I manually started node in the shell and copy&pasted the request. i don't get any error.

Comment: Try changing `console.log('BODY: ' + JSON.stringify(response));` to `console.log('BODY: ' + JSON.stringify(response), body, response.statusCode);`. The statusCode will tell you what status is coming back from the request, anything higher than 299 is an issue. The body will hopefully give you more information too.

Comment: BODY: {"statusCode":200,"body":"1700","headers":{"server":"esp8266-httpd/0.3","connection":"close","content-type":"application/json","access-control-allow-origin":"*"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"192.168.0.250","port":80,"hostname":"192.168.0.250","hash":null,"search":"?param=thermostat_manualsetpoint","query":"param=thermostat_manualsetpoint","pathname":"/control/thermostat.cgi","path":"/control/thermostat.cgi?param=thermostat_manualsetpoint","href":"http://192.168.0.250/control/thermostat.cgi?param=thermostat_manualsetpoint"},"method":"POST"

Comment: ,"headers":{"content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","content-length":4}}} 1700 200

Comment: It's not showing the right value I pass: 2000. Instead it shows "1700", the actual value of the temperature

Comment: I suppose the problem it's not nodejs related ... I wish I could explain you better wht I'm using and what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The same request but with GET, gives me the actual temperature: http://192.168.0.250/control/thermostat.cgi?param=thermostat_manualsetpoint

Comment: Instead, with POST and the value of the temperature, it should change the value of the target temperature. It seems that the POST request is not working and it gets interpreted a GET request

Comment: The thermostat C code that handles the requests: 
  if(os_strcmp(buff,"thermostat_manualsetpoint")==0) {
   if(connData->post->len>0) {
    sysCfg.thermostat1manualsetpoint=(int)atoi(connData->post->buff);
    CFG_Save();
    os_printf("Handle thermostat manual setpoint save (%d)\n",(int)sysCfg.thermostat1manualsetpoint);
   } else {
    os_sprintf(buff, "%d", (int)sysCfg.thermostat1manualsetpoint);
   }
}